# Python: Obter URL de pasta

Tags: python, imagem, url, diretório

Como obter o caminho/local da imagem mais recente armazenada em uma pasta x utilizando Python?

Comment: O que você entende por "URL de uma imagem em uma pasta"?

Comment: Ah, perdão. Vou editar. É o local da foto, o endereço/caminho.